# Show if $\{a_n^2\}$ is bounded then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

If $\{a_n^2\}$ is bounded then I know for a non-negative number $M$, $\mid a_n^2 \mid \leq M, \forall n$.

How do I show that this leads to $\{a_n\}$ being bounded?

$\mid a_n^2 \mid \leq M$

$-M \leq a_n^2 \leq M$

but now I don't think I can replace $M$ with $\sqrt{M}$, can I?

$-\sqrt{M} \leq a_n \leq \sqrt{M}$ is probably allowed, but how do I justify this?

Comment: Letting $\sqrt{}$ denote the positive branch of the square root, your justification is correct:
$$|a_{n}| \leq \sqrt{M}.$$

Comment: Is $a_n$ restricted to be real?

Comment: Yes, $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

The squaring function $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^2$, is a strictly monotonic bijection, hence its inverse function $f^{-1} : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is also a strictly monotonic bijection. So $|a^2_n| \le M$ if and only if $|a_n| \le \sqrt{M}$. And that last inequality is equivalent to $-\sqrt{M} \le a_n \le \sqrt{M}$ simply by the definition of absolute values.